# Understanding FromContinuedFraction

Tags: documentation, continued-fractions

In the detail section of the documentation page for `FromContinuedFraction` we read that:

> FromContinuedFraction[{a1,a2,…,{b1,b2,…}}] returns the exact number whose continued fraction terms start with the ai, then consist of cyclic repetitions of the bi.

I do not quite undestand the meaning of this sentence and there are no example for this: can anyone explain what it means?

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction you find what a "continued fraction" is, and the mentioned function gives what it should: the value of this continued fraction

Comment: @mgamer I know what a continued fraction is, I do not understand the quoted sentence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fractions are always representable with a finite length continued fractions. Any number can be represented via an infinite continued fraction expansion. But inbetween those two extremes there are some numbers (more specifically the [irrational solutions of quadratic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Periodic_continued_fractions)), which after some initial digits exhibit a periodic continued fraction. This periodic part is what the 'cyclic repetitions of bi' refer to. Let's look at an example:

```
ContinuedFraction[Sqrt[3]]
FromContinuedFraction[%]
Sqrt[3] - FromContinuedFraction[{1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}]
% // N
```

> {1, {1, 2}}
>
> Sqrt[3]
>
> -989/571 + Sqrt[3]
>
> 1.77079*10^-6

Here the first `1` in `{1, {1, 2}}` is the leading continued fraction digit followed by an infinite number of repetitions of `{1,2}`. Explicitly following this pattern 
and computing the difference to the exact number shows how the first few digits of the expansion approximate `Sqrt[3]`.